# Trim Video and Overwrite Original

Tags: macos, quicktime

I often need to trim videos and simply want to overwrite the original file.

Using QuickTime Player I need to

- open and trim the video
- save the video to a new file (unfortunately it does not show the folder the original video is in)
- find the new file and move it back to the original folder

Is there a quicker way to do this? Like on the iPhone where I can just select *overwrite original*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag the original into the save dialog to have it put you in the appropriate folder, and with the same file name as the file you dragged. Then you can just save and overwrite.

Comment: That's a cool trick! It's a bit awkward but it works!

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a keyboard shortcut or do I need to drag?

Comment: If the original is in one of the pre-defined shortcuts in the Finder's "Go" menu, you can use that.

Comment: I discovered that I can set a shortcut for the Finder `Copy Path` command and then type `/` & paste in the save dialog. Thanks!